# javafx to exe, вес

Tags: java, javafx, exe

нормально-ли что exe версия приложения с одним окном весит больше 200 метров, а его jar 14?
Использовал нативный конвертер intelijIdea.
Если это не норма, то подскажите чем конвертировать в exe...

Answer (score 0):

Это нормально, для работы java нужна VJM, он сует в exe'шник все необходимое для нормальной работы java приложения. Лучше использовать https://github.com/ReadyTalk/avian. exe'шник выходит около 2мб